# How to download files in chunks using google drive api in java?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am able to download files using google drive api as a single file but I want to download files in chunks of size let's say 5 MB for large files. This is the code for direct downloading.

```
session.service.files().get(id).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(asOutputStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `RANGE` header with the range of bytes per the documentation [Google Drive API - Partial Downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#partial_download)